# Ajax no logra conectar con servidor

Tags: ajax, laravel, app

Hice una app mobile utilizando phonegap. Utilizo Ajax para traer los datos de un server. En el server hay un webservice hecho en Laravel, que devuelve los datos en json. Este es el codigo:

```
jQuery(function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".loader").show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://miIp/public/menu',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#conectionError").hide();

                        if(data == 1){
                            $('#liveStreaming').show();
                            $("#live_choose").show();
                            $(".btn_menu").hide();
                        }
                        if(data == 0){
                            $('#liveStreaming').hide();
                            $("#live_choose").hide();
                            $(".btn_menu").show();
                            $('#liveStreaming').hide();
                        }
                        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        $(".loader").hide();
                        var divHeight = $("#conectionError").height();
                        var imgHeight = $("#conectionErrorImg").height();
                        var imgMargin = (divHeight - imgHeight)/2;

                        $("#conectionErrorImg").css("margin-top", imgMargin);

                        $("#conectionError").show();
                    },
                    async: true
                });
            });
        });
```

Probé la aplicación localmente. La aplicación laravel la tenia en xampp, y funcionaba perfecto. Incluso compile la app con phonegapp, me la instalé, y funcionaba perfecto.

Hoy subí la app laravel a un servidor cloud en WIROOS, y la app no trae nada. Pego los links en el explorador y me trae correctamente los datos, pero ajax siempre se va por el error, nunca llega a conectar.

Supuse que tal vez sea algún problema de permisos (Estoy usando Vesta Panel), pero no logro entender que sucede.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: creo que es un problema de crossdomain , localhost te va a funcionar vas a tener que ambiar tu configuracion de apache

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es un problema de CORS, lo cual debes configurar en tu server para poder consumir desde tu app. Y aque usas Laravel, te recomiento usar el paquete [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Con ese paquete puedes configurar cabeceras de control para CORS usando los Middleware de Laravel.

Te recomiendo leer un poco sobre CORS para que tengas una idea aproximada del por qué no puedes acceder a los recursos de tu server desde el app: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Espero haber ayudado en algo. Saludos.